# How to pass seleced file details to another page - UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I have a launcher page(MainPage1.xaml).There is a button to select video file from device. Now I want to play that selected file on next page (MainPage2.xaml). How can I get this selcted file `StorageFile file` on next page?

```
  private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        StorageFile file;

        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        foreach (string extension in FileExtensions.Video)
        {
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(extension);
        }
        file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage2), file);
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Which part is not working?

Comment: how to access this 'file' on next page?

Comment: inside onNavigatedto Event do `StorageFile file = e.Parameter as StorageFile`. This is in `MainPage2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the `OnNavigatedTo()` method in your page (next Page) which is expecting the `StorageFile`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Parameter != null)
     {
        StorageFile file = (StorageFile)e.Parameter;
     }
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: This will work inconsistently for a StorageFile. The Parameter needs to be a basic type

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information through your answer..it is really helpful .. the answer I had recommended was based completely on the question that was asked..

Answer (score 0):

**Override OnNavigatedTo in DestinationPage**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

  var parameters = e.Parameter;  // it will give your file reference
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this: as noted in other answers, the second argument to the Navigate method will be passed to OnNavigatedTo in the NavigationEventArgs.Parameter .

This is good for basic types, but isn't sufficient for a StorageFile. Quoting from the [Frame.Navigate docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_Navigate_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_System_Object_Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Animation_NavigationTransitionInfo_):

> parameter Object  The navigation parameter to pass to the target page;
>   must have a basic type (string, char, numeric, or GUID) to support
>   parameter serialization using GetNavigationState.

The StorageFile will work for a direct navigation, but since it isn't serializable it can get lost in the back stack, while suspending, etc.

Instead of passing the StorageFile directly stow it in a global dictionary and pass a string or GUID key that the OnNavigatedTo method can use to look up the StorageFile on the other side.

For the specific case of a StorageFile you can use the FutureAccessList. See [Track recently used files and folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders#future-access-list)